# Error: An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

My code:

```
removeIndexCart: (state, action) => {
      const IteamIndex_dec = state.cart.findIndex(
        (iteam) => iteam.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty >= 1) {
        const dltiteams = (state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty -= 1);
        console.log([...state.cart, dltiteams]);

        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [...state.cart],
        };
      } else if (state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty === 1) {
        const data = state.cart.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload);

        return {
          ...state,
          cart: data,
        };
      }
    },
```

I wanted to reduce the selected products with index, but I encountered this error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the reducer function is both trying to modify the proxy `state` with Immer (automatically applied by `redux-toolkit`), and returning a new value, which caused the error.

More about using [redux-toolkit reducer with immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers)

Perhaps consider to always modify the proxy `state` in the reducer (only works in `redux-toolkit` where Immer is used internally), without returning a new value:

```
// Only works in redux-toolkit with immer

removeIndexCart: (state, action) => {
  const IteamIndex_dec = state.cart.findIndex(
    (iteam) => iteam.id === action.payload.id
  );
  if (state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty > 1) {
    state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty -= 1;
  } else if (state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty === 1) {
    state.cart = state.cart.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload);
  }
},
```

Alternatively, perhaps try always return a new value, without modifying the proxy `state`:

```
removeIndexCart: (state, action) => {
  const IteamIndex_dec = state.cart.findIndex(
    (iteam) => iteam.id === action.payload.id
  );
  if (state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty > 1) {
    const updatedItem = {
      ...state.cart[IteamIndex_dec],
      qnty: state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty - 1,
    };

    const updatedCart = [...state.cart];
    updatedCart[IteamIndex_dec] = updatedItem;

    return {
      ...state,
      cart: updatedCart,
    };
  } else if (state.cart[IteamIndex_dec].qnty === 1) {
    const data = state.cart.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload);

    return {
      ...state,
      cart: data,
    };
  }
},
```